# Likelihood ratio test with simple hypotesis.

Tags: reference-request, maximum-likelihood

Does anyone know material that's available online about likelihood ratio test with simple hypothesis? It's should be something that can be cited, not online page. The "Introduction to: Probability and Statistics" is not available. I have searched all over internet, and cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [page](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter8/8_4_5_likelihood_ratio_tests.php). This is the book used for the introductory course on probability and statistics at my department.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a book.

Comment: It is a book. What I referred to is exactly the same as section 8.4.5 in the actual book.

Comment: True, thank you.